# How to add data labels to boxplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, boxplot

I am having difficulties figuring out how to replacing the 1, 2, 3, 4 data labels on the boxplot with "nok", "msft, "ibm" and "aapl".  See the image, where I highlighted in yellow

I thought this line of code would add them, but it just adds the numbers:

ax.set_xticklabels(['nok', 'msft', 'ibm', 'aapl'])

[image]

The rest of the code is below:

```
data = [df['nok'],  df['msft'],  df['ibm'],  df['aapl']]
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.set_xticklabels(['nok', 'msft', 'ibm', 'appl'])
ax.set_title('BoxPlot Example')
ax.set_xlabel('Stock')
ax.set_ylabel('Price')
ax.grid(zorder=0)
ax.boxplot(data, widths = 0.6, patch_artist = True)
```

Can you help?

Thanks,

Paul

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `labels` parameter on your `boxplot` call.

```
labels = ['nok', 'msft', 'ibm', 'appl']
ax.boxplot(data, widths = 0.6, patch_artist = True, labels=labels)
```